# Calling function from std::array of function pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, std, function-pointers

I can't figure out how to call function pointer stored in `std::array` which is member of class.

```
namespace logic {
    class Chance {
        std::array<void(logic::Chance::*)(), 15> m_redChances;
    };
}

void logic::Chance::redChance1 {
   std::cout << "Red chance one\n";
}

logic::Chance::Chance()
{
    m_redChances[0] = &Chance::redChance1;
}
```

It looks fine till now, but when I want to call this function in another member function, nothing seems to work. Only first line compiles, but it doesnt call my function. Rest are giving erros:

```
logic::Chance::anotherMemberFunction() {
    m_redChances[0];
    (*m_redChances[0]*)();
    (*logic::Chance::m_redChances[0])();
    m_redChances[0]();
    *m_redChances[0]();
    *logic::Chance::m_redChances[0]();
    *logic::Chance::m_redChances[0];
    *(*m_redChances[0])();
}
```

> operand of "*"must be a pointer type

and

> expression precending parentheses of apprent call must have
>   (pointer-to-) function type

EDIT#

So I tried to use `std::function` and had to change class design a bit, I want to achieve something like this

```
struct Foo {
    std::array<std::function<void(Foo&)>, 3> funArray;

    Foo() {     
        funArray[0] = &Foo::fun1;
        funArray[1] = &Foo::fun2;       
    }

    void fun1() {
        std::cout << "fun1\n";
    }

    void fun2() {
        std::cout << "fun2\n";
    }   

    std::function<void(Foo&)> getFunction(int i) {
        return funArray[i];
    }
};  

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.getFunction(0);
    std::cin.get();
}
```

As you can guess, this isn't calling my function and I again, tried every combination to return this correctly, but cant figure it out, thats the only one that compiles, but does nothing. How can I return a function call of function sotred in `std::array` by another function? A bit messy, but hope you get what I mean.

Comment: A member function that's not declared in the class definition, can't be defined later. That may be one source of your errors. Also, a function definition needs at least an empty formal arguments list, `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `std::function` example you can simply change

```
foo.getFunction(0);
```

to instead say

```
foo.getFunction(0)(foo);
```

This has to do with the same reason talked about in the other answers, a pointer to member-function is not in itself linked to an object. It needs a `this` to work on.

If you want to bind the std::function to a specific object you can use a 
lambda to do that, like this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <functional>

struct Foo {
    std::array<std::function<void()>, 3> funArray; // Notice the change in signature to void()

    Foo() {     
        funArray[0] = [&](){ fun1(); }; // Here & is catching this by reference and this lambda will always call fun1 on the current object.
        funArray[1] = [&](){ fun2(); };
    }

    void fun1() {
        std::cout << "fun1\n";
    }

    void fun2() {
        std::cout << "fun2\n";
    }   

    std::function<void()> getFunction(int i) {
        return funArray[i];
    }
};  

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.getFunction(0)(); // We get a function returned, so we need to call if by adding one more () at the end


    auto storedFunction = foo.getFunction(1); // We can also store it
    storedFunction(); // and call it later
}
```

Comment: I modified a code a bit so my functions can return something. `std::array<std::function<std::string()>, 3> funArray; ` and inside `Foo()` constructor `funArray[0] = [&]() -> std::string { fun1(); }; `. But it doesnt compile, this error shows up: **error C4716: '<lambda_f7e6bb611c290018a3679342f5296412>::operator()': must return a value**

Comment: Change it to return fun1(); inside the lambda so the lambda return the value from the function.

Answer (score 3):

`std::array<void(logic::Chance::*)(), 15> m_redChances` is an array of pointers to a **non-`static` *member function*** of objects of class `Chance`. Therefore, you need to apply the object where the pointed-to member function is going to be called.

In the statement:

```
(*logic::Chance::m_redChances[0])();
```

no object is provided. On which object's data is that call going to be performed?

Considering `chance` an object of `Chance` and `chance_ptr` a pointer to an object of the same type, the call would be performed this way:

```
(chance.*m_redChances[0])();
(chance_ptr->*m_redChances[0])();
```

That is, by using the operators `.*` and `->*`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

A member function needs to be called on an object, to serve as the `*this` *current object*. You use the `.*` and `->*` operators to call it with an object. E.g. `(o.*mf)( args )`.

Silly-fact noted by Andrei in his Modern C++ Programming book: `o.*mf` produces a callable entity that has no type.

In C++11 and later you can use `std::function` to effectively store such an object+function pointer pair, as a callable entity. Some other languages support it directly. E.g., it corresponds to a C# *delegate*.

---

Example.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    void blah() { cout << "Blah!" << endl; }
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    array<void (Foo::*)(), 3> mf = {nullptr, nullptr, &Foo::blah};

    Foo o;
    Foo* o_ptr = &o;

    (o_ptr->*mf[2])();
}
```

Comment: What if I need to use in on `this` object? Iv tried `(this->*m_redChances[0])();` for example and it didnt work

Comment: "Didn't work" is too vague. But that's the `->*` operator, you have that right. E.g. `(this->*mf)()`. Alternatively you can dereference `this` and use `.*`, like `((*this).*mf)()`.

Comment: I added a full example to the answer.